# How do I identify a British idiom from an American one?

Tags: idioms, american-english, british-english, dialects

I live outside the US and the UK. I just started reading a book titled "Speak English like an American". The book teaches numerous idioms but I don't know if these idioms are usable outside the the US.

Are there any characteristics that help a learner to recognize the origin of an idiom?

As an example, is there a process I can follow to determine which of these idioms are American, English or Australian in origin?

- go belly-up
- give someone the ax
- sharp as a tack
- top dollar
- gung ho
- not give a hoot
- stand a chance

Comment: The following is an interesting paper on this issue:   ***Idioms – Differences and Usage in American English and British***  https://merikari.wordpress.com/2007/01/23/idioms-differences-and-usage-in-american-english-and-british-english/

Comment: As to Q3, you could invest in a good idioms dictionary. The _Collins Cobuild Pocket Idioms Dictionary_ is one such, and states in the Introduction: "If an idiom is used only or mainly in one geographical variety of English, we show this at the beginning of the explanation, for example by putting 'British' or 'mainly American'". So, for example, it identifies _to go nuclear_ (become enraged) as a British idiom. And _out of left field_ (unexpected) as mainly American. As a BE speaker myself, and not familiar with baseball, this was totally opaque until I saw the explanation.

Comment: for the US, that is probably "Not give a hoot".

Comment: This is too broad. But I can't flag because it has a bounty.

Comment: I thought questions that had a bounty couldn't be closed?? Didn't this have a bounty?

Comment: @Andrew Leach With only one vague comment you held the question?

Comment: @Mari-LouA I followed Meta Stack Exchange's guidelines and wrote a custom flag! :)

Comment: @curiousdannii what's there to smile about? As far as I know the rules state that bounty questions cannot be closed, I'm not going to rummage and look for the exact rules, but you said so yourself, you couldn't vote to close b/c there was a bounty. I'm getting tired of mods who arbitrarily close questions single-handedly, or worse,  delete highly-upvoted questions.

Comment: **VOTED to reopen**. Too broad my foot... there are two answers after four days.

Comment: Apparently there is a loophole of sorts http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14591/how-can-we-close-questions-with-bounties. People can flag questions which they believe are inappropriate, and mods refund the bounty before closing the question. This is the first time I have seen this course of action.  I do not think this question deserved to be closed. What was wrong with waiting until the bounty period ended, and then, and only then, closing the question?

Comment: Edited the question. A warning to the OP that the question was too broad and risked being closed might have been a considerate gesture.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thanks for tightening the question. And I did warn them with my first comment.

Comment: @Mari-LouA So one can add a bounty just to prevent a question being closed?

Comment: Here's a way to test each of those phrases: use google NGrams for each phrase, but compare British with American corpora. For example, [`(sharp as a tack):eng_gb_2012,(sharp as a tack):eng_us_2012`](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=(sharp+as+a+tack)%3Aeng_gb_2012%2C(sharp+as+a+tack)%3Aeng_us_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3). Of course consider all the usual caveats with Google NGrams.

Comment: @Mitch did you know that a question could still be closed while there was a bounty? I certainly didn't **"A bounty can be started on a question two days after the question was asked."** Which kinda tells me that the community didn't think this was such a terrible question, I didn't. That doesn't mean I couldn't see its flaws, but I also saw its merits. Since its last edit, it's also gained three upvotes, which means that other users think the question is useful. Please, could you go to chat and drum up some support?

Comment: The question is still too broad, in my opinion. The list could be subsumed into Question 3. But **Question 3**? SE questions should ask one thing, in order that answers may answer it and the asker may choose the answer which helped them best. What this question calls for is a treatise on the usage of American idioms outside America. '[If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)." I attempted to get the three questions into a manageable form, in order to help with that, and failed. Others may do better.

Comment: @Josh61 Thanks a lot. The link actually answers all the questions.

Comment: @Mari-LouA The bounty was offered by the OP so it can hardly be taken as an indication of the question's popularity with the community. In any case, bounties are given by a single user so, again, have nothing to do with community opinion. That said, the rule across all of SE is "ask one question at a time". I agree that these are interesting questions but asking the 4 of them together in a single post is pretty much the definition of too broad and offering a bounty on your close-worthy question should not be a way of keeping it open.

Comment: @terdon I understand your point of view, but if you would kindly do the needful and vote to reopen, I have an answer that addresses the broadness _and_ answers, where it can, the particulars.

Comment: @terdon I didn't mean that the bounty is an indication of popularity, but the fact, as far as I'm aware, there were no votes to close this question after two days, **is** indicative that the community considered it to be on topic. The PO has been voted on hold by two people, not five.

Comment: Still too broad. Just pick one subquestion and ask the others separately.

Comment: @curiousdannii  It was fine, the post received six upvotes after I edited it. Now the OP's main request *How many British and American idioms are either very similar or identical? Is it possible to give a rough estimate or percentage?* has been altogether deleted, and mitch's introduction doesn't make much sense. Deleting the question if an American idiom can be used in the UK, means that David Pugh and Jeremy Thomson's answers sound disconnected from the OP as it stands now.

Comment: (cont'd) This is the trouble when an edit has to be peer reviewed by two users who know nothing about the OP's history. Did they look at the answers posted, I don't think they did. And I'm surprised you, (danini) didn't consider the answers that had already been posted before proposing an edit, that shaved off two questions. A post which started with five questions, that I reduced to three (necessary) so that the post could be reopened, has now been (unnecessarily) further reduced.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Take it to [Meta] please.

Comment: Good idea, I'll think about it.

Comment: British idioms all have little marks on them, showing a randy lion, a chained unicorn, and other tiny hallucinations, mostly unrecognizable. They also have been known to crawl backwards on damp nights with foxglove smeared over their left ears. *No one knows why.* American idioms, on the other hand, are plain. This is why Yanks think Brits are eccentrics.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24855/discussion-on-question-by-phpst-how-do-i-identify-a-british-idiom-from-an-americ).

Answer (score 8):

The rule of thumb is, I think, that the Brits are much more likely to be familiar with American idioms than the other way round. We have been relentlessly exposed to them since the war; Murricans have been exposed to ours only if they are fans of Monty Python, Blackadder and The Office, which not all of them are.

For example, my own language is infiltrated by baseball metaphors that I do not actually understand: *home run, left field, strike out* etc. in addition to the obvious *ball-park*. An American using cricketing metaphors like *sticky wicket, knocked for six* or *stumped*, I don't think so.

You probably know the classic traps. British smokers in the US ought not say that they are *going out for a fag*. Do not invite hungry Leftpondians to look for a *chippy*. (Personal experience there) A British girl on a transatlantic ship who wished to make an early start asked my handsome Canadian friend to *come and knock her up* at eight o'clock, and, as a gentleman, he obliged....

Comment: You should add links to the different idioms, just in case our American friends do not get it. Love the answer btw!

Comment: @Mari-Lou: How do I make a link to personal experiences? If they don't get it, let them ask.

Comment: OK, the only one I'm unclear about is "chippy" which I know is slang for (fish) and chips restaurant/takeaway  (AmEng *french fries*). What does *chippy* mean for Americans? Oh, that your American friend didn't know where to look...?

Comment: @Mari-Lou: Prostitute. Might be regional. The Canadian came from B.C., but I think it works at least in the Pacific North-West of the USA. BTW, again for our American friends, the British "chippy" is or was the fish-and-chip _shop_, not the dish. The chips are not much like the french fries Americans know, but fat and greasy. The whole thing is, of course, a cholesterol bomb, but walking past a chippy can evoke a Pavlovian response in Brits of a certain age. (Walking past an American chippy, let's not go there.)

Comment: @David: some restaurants serve fat and greasy french fries in the U.S., too; I don't perceive the British chips as something that you never see in an American restaurant.

Comment: @PeterShor. OK, you have been there, me not. I know American fries only from their chains; and the etiolated, desiccated style dominates restaurants here in Switzerland too.

Comment: For *knock up*: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=knock+up&defid=425306

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Actually, chippy is not very specific. In the first half of the previous century it could refer either to a prostitute or a promiscuous woman - popular American culture often confused the two. The term has gradually been falling out of use. See https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=chippy%2Cchippie&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cchippy%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cchippie%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Sticky wicket and stumped are used in the US.

Comment: We Americans have to suffer through all sorts of nautical idiom thanks to you all.  You can handle a few baseball terms, I'm sure.  And *slam-dunk* to boot.  Also, I live in Seattle, and *chippy* doesn't mean anything about prostitution or food.

Comment: I hadn't come across _knock me up_ to, presumably, mean _knock and wake me up_. Could it be regional? I spent 4 years living in Yorkshire, could it be a southern expression?

Answer (score 7):

TL;DR

This is like asking how many words are in the English language. Everyone is different, words are created everyday (and fade away slowly), so naming a specific number is misleading. But for a single idiom, you *can* compare it’s frequency of usage in the US vs UK using corpora (COA/BNC or Google NGrams)

Details:

First a general observation: for questions of these sorts that involve all of a set (however well defined), it will *always* depend. A particular idiom may be one in the US and not in the UK, and the other way for another. And everything is vague, with degrees of acceptability.

But to answer your explicit questions directly:

- (The main question) 1. How many British and American idioms are either very similar or identical? Is it possible to give a rough estimate or percentage?

Answer: This is a terribly broad question. The concept of a word is already slippery, an idiom even moreso, especially with figurative meanings. How many words are there in the English language? There’s no good quantitative assessment of that. The OED says it has 171,000 words. Are all of those in every ‘English’ speaker’s head. It is said that most adults have  vocabulary of 20 to 30 thousand. Not everybody recognizes or uses the same vocabulary. Even though the number of idioms should be much less, what is an idiom in AmE and what is one in BrE needs lots of interviews with individuals to ask them what they recognize and what sounds normal to them, a daunting task. This task has so much variability and vagueness involved that any kind of percentage estimate will be meaningless. Now that’s for the entire (not well defined) set of idioms in both varieties.

Or more mathematically speaking, you are asking: what is the set of American idioms, what is the set of British idioms, what is the intersection of these two sets. And the response is that these sets are too vague to define precisely; membership of any particular idiom in any of these sets is probabilistic (even for an individual speaker they are fuzzy).

So, no, there is no way to give a percentage because defining idiom, defining British vs American, and then counting are all so vague and problematic that math just doesn’t apply.

- Question 2: Is it OK to use an American idiom in a British setting?

Answer: Assuming that you know that an idiom is American and not British (and these labels are pretty slippery), it’ll be acceptable if it is recognizable. That’s sort of empty because what does acceptable mean other than that it is recognizable. I don’t think you’ll be thrown out of English high court for it (but a bunch of old white dudes in wigs might laugh at you or you might never be allowed to see the Queen again).

If no one recognizes the idiom then it’s probably not ‘OK’ or rather it will just be weird since no one will understand you.

As someone else said, American media is more pervasive than British so (in a very vague sense) more idioms with specifically American origins will be understood in the UK than the other way round.

- Question 3: Are there any characteristics that help a learner to recognize the origin of an idiom?

I’ve been giving the impression that there’s no hope here but that’s not really the case. I’m sure there are numerous websites and books about explaining American idioms to the British. But the provenance of an idiom is usually difficult, and each one needs its own separate research, often answered in specialty articles in print or online (ELU is in spirit an attempt to have a place where that sort of thing can be asked about a specific idiom).

But if you’re given an idiom and asked at gunpoint if it’s more likely to be British or American, there might be some heuristics, but I doubt it.

- Question (list): How can I tell which of these idioms are American, English or Australian in origin?

There are countless dictionaries of idioms in English in print and online. Sometimes they tell you that the idiom is primarily AmE, BrE, or AusE, or sometimes not. Or the volume will be about American idioms in particular without conceding itself if it is recognized in the UK. You’ll have to check those books.

In the end, for your first three questions, there is no general comparison, but one can certainly find out something about individual idioms.

About individual idioms there is hope though. There are some things you can do online quickly to tell if an idiom is more common in the US or the UK (sadly I can’t find anything online for other varieties of English so you’ll have to pick up a book on Australian idioms if that’s your thing).

One could guess that the more popular an idiom is in a corpus, the more likely its origin is there. But in some sense that doesn't matter because you probably really just want to know if it will be understood there and the relative frequency is exactly that.

But how to determine relative frequency of an idiom? There are the two websites, [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) (a corpus of US English) and [BNC](http://www.natcorp.ox.ac.uk/) (for UK English). You can search your idioms on both and figure the relative frequency in each (they both give absolute frequencies, so they are incomparable, but if you divide by the number of entries, then you can compare. These corpora though separate are well studied and curated so are high quality. They are only written records, not speech.

Another possibility is [Google NGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams). There is a search feature that allows you to track a phrase for a given corpus, and they have an American and a British corpus. An example is

[`appropriation:eng_gb_2012, appropriation:eng_us_2012`](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=appropriation%3Aeng_gb_2012%2Cappropriation%3Aeng_us_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3)

For convenience, I have made the links for your specific requests:

- [went belly up](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%28went%20belly%20up%29%3Aeng_gb_2012%2C%28went%20belly%20up%29%3Aeng_us_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3)
- [give him the ax](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%28give%20him%20the%20ax%29%3Aeng_gb_2012%2C%28give%20him%20the%20ax%29%3Aeng_us_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3)
- [sharp as a tack](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%28sharp%20as%20a%20tack%29%3Aeng_gb_2012%2C%28sharp%20as%20a%20tack%29%3Aeng_us_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3)
- [top dollar](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%28top%20dollar%29%3Aeng_gb_2012%2C%28top%20dollar%29%3Aeng_us_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3)
- [gung ho](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%28gung%20ho%29%3Aeng_gb_2012%2C%28gung%20ho%29%3Aeng_us_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3)
- [don’t give a hoot](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%28don%27t%20give%20a%20hoot%29%3Aeng_gb_2012%2C%28don%27t%20give%20a%20hoot%29%3Aeng_us_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3)
- [stand a chance](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%28stand%20a%20chance%29%3Aeng_gb_2012%2C%28stand%20a%20chance%29%3Aeng_us_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3)

Of course, as with any corpus search, you have to beware of a few things.

- false negatives - leaving out things you should have searched for (I modified some of your items to be what I think will catch better) for example, I think ‘belly up’ appears much more likely without the hyphen. leo spelling variants (ax or axe?) can mess things up.
- false positives - catching things you realize you don’t really want. Suppose you just looked for ‘belly up’. It might include also the common idiom ‘belly up to the bar’.
- OCR - a lot of the text in the Google corpora is scanned and converted to text using optical character recognition. For lots of print (mostly older but still some recent) there are lots of mistakes, so there’s lots of room for capturing or missing unintended things.
- how things are said - what you think people write is not necessarily how they write. ‘give someone the ax’ is a good template but no one will ever write that. ‘give him the ax’  (probably not ‘give her’ or ‘give them’ because it feels to me like an older expression and only recently would language show the latter.

There are countless other caveats here (not particular to Google NGrams, but show up there more often because of the source text). The best defense against these systematic errors is to look at the actual hits and correct your search accordingly to include or exclude.

Comment: Note that the OP was radically edited to eliminate the multiple sub-questions. Luckily the original questions were preserved in my answer so you can see the original intent.

Comment: Would you agree [the edit was harmful](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/250533/how-do-i-identify-a-british-idiom-from-an-american-one#comment547820_250533)? Do you think the edit was necessary, has it improved the post measurably. Where there grammatical errors which impeded comprehension?

Answer (score 2):

> I don't know if those idioms are usable outside the US.

If in doubt don't use them.

> There are some examples that I am not sure about if they are common in UK?
>
> - go belly-up
> - give someone the ax
> - sharp as a tack
> - top dollar
> - gung ho
> - not give a hoot
> - stand a chance

All these sayings are very, very common in UK and Australia.

> 1. How much are British and American idioms similar?

Some are, some aren't.

> 2. Is it OK to say an American idiom in a British setting?

I doubt if you said any of the above bullet point idioms anyone would raise an eyelid. Those are all fine.

However, Americans have a reputation around the world so if you think it might be translated incorrectly steer clear of the idiom. This should answer your Q4.

For example you might not want to be a Brit in America saying something like **Look at the thongs they're wearing** - while this is not an idiom you can see how easily it could be misinterpreted as flip flops.

> 3. Are there some characteristics or hints to help to recognize the origin of them? (for example I guess British idioms generally do not contain impolite words)

I think you would have to look into some British slang to gauge/guess the origin: http://www.effingpot.com/slang.shtml

Same with Aussies too:
http://www.australianexplorer.com/slang/phrases.htm
http://www.australiatravelsearch.com.au/trc/slang.html

> 5. I guess British and Australian idioms are almost the same. Aren't they?

No, not necessarily.

For example many in the list pictured below are **not** common in Australia and would certainly be foreign when used in the USA.

For example it would be easily misunderstood in Australia or America if you said **I'll give you a bell if I need a cockup**.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but I had to chop  the number of questions, so the post stands a better chance of being reopened. You can leave your answer as is or edit. As you wish.

Comment: If you say *"look at the thongs they're wearing"* in the U.S. within sight of a number of women in very skimpy bathing suits, I think the chance of your being misunderstood is virtually zero. On the other hand, if an American went into a shoe store in the U.K. and asked for thongs ...