# How common is the 'object-subject-verb' construction?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, sentence-patterns

E.g. from [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object%E2%80%93subject%E2%80%93verb#English_and_German): *I hate oranges, but apples I'll eat!* or *He's not very interesting, but her I would like to know!*

I understand it is a form only used for emphasis, but how common is it? Is it perceived as something strange to say or is it quite used?

Comment: There's several different kinds. They all indicate focus on the object. Object-fronting (aka Y-movement) is the one in _apples I'll eat_. There's also Left-dislocation, which would produce _Apples, i'll eat them_. Dislocation is a copying rule and leaves a pronoun behind, but Object-fronting is a movement rule and leaves nothihng behind. Many more examples in the [English syntactic rule list](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/haj/Preliminarybufattenedlistoftransformations.pdf).

Comment: My feeling is that it is not common, but not terribly rare. It is not strange (as in foreign) sounding, but it does feel out of the ordinary, maybe a little poetic. If you pick a very simple example, you might be able to check frequency using a corpus (COCA/BNC/Google NGrams). [See how to do that here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/250533/how-do-i-identify-a-british-idiom-from-an-american-one) (that answer is specifically for comparing frequency in corpora; you want to just compare something like 'I like oranges' vs 'Oranges I like'... but choose a better/more frequent phrase.)

Comment: Some particular cases are very common; others less so. Thus, for example, “Now _that_ I can believe” is perfectly commonplace and unexceptional, whereas “Now this version of the events which you have just very unwillingly admitted to me after I almost broke half the bones in your body, I can believe” is quite clumsy because of the length and complexity of the object.